# Applying mutate across columns called using paste in R

Tags: r

I would like to apply a function across columns in a data frame using mutate in dplyr. I would like to reference the columns using paste.

Here's example data, but the actual data set has many columns making the paste functionality key:

```
data <- data.frame(var1 = c(1:4), var2 = (5:8))
data
  var1 var2
1    1    5
2    2    6
3    3    7
4    4    8
```

I've got it working when the columns are called separately without quotes:

```
data <- data %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(
    total = sum(var1,var2)
  )
data
# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Rowwise: 
   var1  var2 total
  <int> <int> <int>
1     1     5     6
2     2     6     8
3     3     7    10
4     4     8    12
```

But, I'd like to be able to call columns with paste:

```
data <- data %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(
    total = sum(paste("var",c(1:2),sep=""))
  )
```

This return this error:

```
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `total`.
x invalid 'type' (character) of argument
ℹ Input `total` is `sum(paste("var", c(1:2), sep = ""))`.
ℹ The error occurred in row 1.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here, we don't need a `rowwise` as `rowSums` would be more efficient

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
     mutate(total = rowSums(.))
```

Or for a subset of columns (using `paste`), we `select` them and use `rowSums`

```
data %>% 
    mutate(total = select(., paste0('var', 1:2)) %>% 
              rowSums)
```

---

If we need to use column names, select the dataset columns within `c_across` and get the `sum` (after `rowwise`)

```
data %>%
   rowwise %>%
   mutate(total = sum(c_across(c(var1, var2)))) %>%
   ungroup
```

Or use `paste` to select columns in `c_across`

```
data %>%
   rowwise %>%
   mutate(total = sum(c_across(paste0('var', 1:2)))) %>%
   ungroup
# A tibble: 4 x 3
#  var1  var2 total
#  <int> <int> <int>
#1     1     5     6
#2     2     6     8
#3     3     7    10
#4     4     8    12
```

---

Or extract the selected columns (`[`) with `cur_data()`

```
data %>%
   rowwise %>%
   mutate(totall = sum(cur_data()[paste0('var', 1:2)])) %>%
   ungroup
# A tibble: 4 x 3
#   var1  var2 totall
#  <int> <int>  <int>
#1     1     5      6
#2     2     6      8
#3     3     7     10
#4     4     8     12
```

Comment: Amazing, thank you akrun! I should have asked before hitting my head against this for an hours. :)